# Blender 2.8 - Sculpt mode hides all objects (Except the mesh being sculpted)

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, sculpt

My map structure looks like this:

```
  - Sculpting(Folder)
    - Reference Images Legs(Folder)
      - Body sideview(Image)
      - Body frontview(Image)
    - Sculpting(Folder)
      - Body Sculpture(Object mesh)
```

This is particularly annoying when sculpting with reference images. My reference images was visible in sculpt mode before but now they've just disappeared. 
I assume this is not a bug but I have no clue what I did to make sculpt mode hide everything except the object being sculpted.

I've tested:

- Alt + H in sculpt mode.
- Move reference images to the same folder as the sculpture.
- Checked that the reference images are checked as visible in the "View tab".
- Include all reference images in selection along with the mesh before going to sculpt mode.

Comment: Maybe you are in local view? Use '/' from the numpad, or the menu 'View>Local view>Toggle'.